# Handlebars inside MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars inside a razor view in an ASP.NET MVC application.

I have a situation where I have to use handlebar's if condition inside a razor's else condition something like below.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
       ....
      @if (CurrentUserRepository.IsInRoleEnums(RoleEnum.TPS_Administrator)) 
           {
               <i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-dark pointer" title="Delete this item" onclick="DeleteNotification({{NotificationId}})"></i>
           }
       else
           {
              //handlebars shown below doesn't work
              {{#if UserCanSetClosed}}
                 <i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-dark pointer" title="Delete this item" onclick="DeleteNotification({{NotificationId}})"></i>
              {{/if}}                    
           }
</script>
```

I know one alternative is to get all the values needed for conditions inside the json passed to handlebars and use it with handlebars conditions in the template. But I want to make use of Razor where ever possible.

Is there any way to get this done?

Note: I tried searching in the repository but this question doesn't seem to be a duplicate one!

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing, now?

Comment: Razor view doesn't compile. The '#' in the line {{#if UserCanSetClosed}}  is treated as preprocessor directive. To be precise, the code inside the else part is treated a C# code and not handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `<text>` tag in Razor might help you get the handlebars syntax processed correctly by the View Engine.

Try this sample code:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

  @if (CurrentUserRepository.IsInRoleEnums(RoleEnum.TPS_Administrator)) 
  {
    <text><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-dark pointer" title="Delete this item" onclick="DeleteNotification({{NotificationId }})"></i></text>
  }
  else
  {
      //handlebars shown below doesn't work
          <text>{{#if UserCanSetClosed}}</text>
          <text><i class="fas fa-trash-alt text-dark pointer" title="Delete this item" onclick="DeleteNotification({{NotificationId}})"></i></text>
          <text>{{/if}}</text>
  }
</script>
```